# indexOf method on an array in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var y = [1,2,3];
(y.indexOf(1) > -1) ? console.log(true) : '';
```

why above code don't work? I thought it's possible to check 1 in y which is an array?

Comment: `y.indexOf(1)` will return `0` as `1` is at the 0th index in array. To check if an element is in array, use `array.indexOf(1) !== -1` or `array.includes(1)` for latest env.

Comment: Now that you've "fixed" the code in your question, what exactly is your question?!?

Comment: What do you mean by _don't work?_. What is expected output? Please see [mcve] and [edit] the question.

Answer (score 3):

[`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) is zero based, as all indices of arrays and strings. If an item is not in the array, then it return `-1`, otherwise it returns the index of the item.

```js
var y = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(y.indexOf(1) !== -1);
```

Comment: @Tushar, to what ...? i think the op is confused about the concept of `indexOf`.

Answer (score 0):

`indexOf` returns the first matching position of the value in the array.

`1` appears in position `0`.

`0 > 1` is `false`.

You need to test if the position is greater than `-1` to see if it appears in the array at all.

---

Since writing this answer, the question has been edited to use `-1`. The code in the question now works as desired.

Comment: Rewording: `1` _is_ in position `0` in the array `y`.

Answer (score 0):

It's because in JS indexes starts at 0th place.

So `1` is in 0th place, `2` is in 1st place and so on